# Prevent escaped ampersand in query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my mailer, I am generating a link to my sign up form so that I can include it in the email to the user.  I'd like to prepopulate the sign up form with the user's name and email address.

I create an instance variable @signup_query like so:

```
@signup_query = "?name=" << 
                CGI.escape(@name) << 
                "&" << 
                "email=" << 
                CGI.escape(@email)
```

But when I call `link_to` in my view, Rails encodes the query string, which adds 'amp;' to the '&'.  As a result, my `params` hash has key 'amp;email' instead of key 'email' so in my sign up view, I have this ugliness:

```
= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', :value => params['amp;email']
```

This works but I know there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
link_to "Sign up", my_signup_url(name: CGI.escape(@name), email: CGI.escape(@email))
```

in your mailer.

For more details on link_to use [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: as I mentioned in my OP, link_to encodes the ampersand in the query string so this doesn't change anything (although it is a nicer way to generate the query string).

Comment: Just tried it in my rails console, got it : `root_path(foo: CGI.escape('foo'), bar: CGI.escape('bar'))` and i got a well formated path : `/?foo=foo&bar=bar` with the ampersand. Can you give me the code you use for your not-working `link_to` ?

Comment: Sorry @Remi I moved on a few days ago and no longer am working on this.